# Airflow DAG script print the value in logs

Tags: python, airflow

Actually I was passing JSON {"Column": "ABC123"} in Airflow before triggering it and in DAG script

I have written the code as below in DAG script

```
 variable1 = "['Column']"
 variable2 = variable1[3:6]

 print( {variable2} )
```

Actually I want to print the value as 123 in Airflow logs but it is not printing in the logs...DAG runs successful but not able to print the value in logs whatever I passed to column while triggering DAG

Comment: _'{"Column: "ABC123"}'_   is not valid JSON, I think you meant _'{"Column": "ABC123"}'_--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I use to see the logs inside the Airflow GUI is the library **loggings**, already inside Python.

You could try using, as an example: `logging.info(var2)`

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

PD: Printing sth (Using basic print) is shown in my Airflow GUI logs, so not sure if this will help.

Comment: I have imported logging module in DAG script and used logging.info(variable2)...but still I am not able to print the values in logs